# Sum all previous every row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Result table

[image]

my expectation query

[image]

help me please, how to get data sum_of_previous from total_point like that

I am using lag() but that only get last 1 previous field i need all previous every row running and sum that

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM() Over()` window aggregate function instead of `LAG`. `LAG` can used to find the only one previous row in ordered set

```
Select id,
       total_point,
       sum(total_point)over(order by Id)
From yourtable
```